# field name not exist

Tags: python, odoo-13

I'm trying to view the form in odoo but I got these errors

```
Field `name` does not exist
```

Error context:
View `user`
[view_id: 1091, xml_id: n/a, model: user, parent_id: n/a]
None" while parsing /home/syafiqah/special/odoo/custom_addons/LeaveAdil/views/user.xml:2, near

this is my user.py file:

```
class LeaveAdiluser (models .ModeL):
    _name = "user"
    _description = "user time off table"

name = fields.Char(string="name", required=True)
description = fields.Text(string="description ")
start_date = fieLlds.Integer(string="start date")
end_date = fields.Integer(string="end date")
requested_days = fields.Text(string="requested days")
```

this is my user.xml file:

```
<?xmL version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="user_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">user</field>
        <field name="nodeL">user</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="description"/>
                <field name="start_date"/>
                <field name="end_date"/>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>>
    <record id="action_user" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">User</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">user</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type='html'>
            <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiting_face"> Create LeaveAdil User!</p>
        </field>
    </record>
    <menuitem id="LeaveAdil_root" name="LeaveAdil" sequence="0" web_icon="static/description/icon.jpg"/>
    <menuitem id="LeaveAdil_user_root" name="user" parent="LeaveAdil_root" sequence="0"/>
    <menuitem id="LeaveAdil_user" name="user" parent="LeaveAdil_user_root" action="action_user" sequence="0"/>
</odoo>
```

The errors mention about a field name not exist, but I could not understand the errors. Can anyone tell me what the causes and how to fix them?

Comment: Put code and xml as text in question

Comment: Fix your indentation in the user.py file the fields should be in the same line as the description try checking the indentations in the default code.

Comment: Already did, but it still shows the errors.